# Плавный поворот элемента

Tags: css

Хочу сделать плавный поворот, но не получается, хотя я все указал. Как это реализовать?
Макет:

```css
.left-part {
 display: inline-block;
background: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#all {
transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id='all'>
<div class='left-part'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите делать это при открытии страницы - нужно воспользоваться `@keyframes`

```css
.left-part {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: rotate 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {transform: rotate(0)}
  100% {transform: rotate(30deg)}
}
```

```html
<div id='all'>
<div class='left-part'></div>
</div>
```

---

Если при наведении то достаточно указания transition у элемента

```css
.left-part {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
}

div.left-part:hover{
  transform: rotate(30deg)
}
```

```html
<div id='all'>
<div class='left-part'></div>
</div>
```

---

Так же можно отложить добавку класса, в котором задается поворот, и тогда все сработает как и с наведением.

```js
setTimeout(e => $('.left-part').addClass('rotate'))
```

```css
.left-part {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.left-part.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='left-part'></div>
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы дополнить ответ, сделав вариант как через @keyframes, но не на css, а на jquery?

Comment: @lIamreadyда, конечно

Answer (score 0):

Вот это

```
transition: 1s
```

Нужно указать с элементом. над каким происходят изменения. В данный момент у Вас `transition` стоит у родителя